# how do i use string replace to remove a carrage return from a string

Tags: php

Hi how do I use string replace to remove a carrage return from a string

here is the string:

```
{ $content = '<p>some random text <a href=
 "http://url.co.uk/link/">link text</a> some more random text.</p>'}
```

and here is the sring replace command

```
{$content=str_replace('carrage return', '', $content);}
```

The think I cant seem to find is what to replace 'carrage return' with.  The reason for this is that I am doing a reg expression on the string which fails if there is a carrage return in the serached for string as that then doesnt match the reg expression.

Also on an asside note if some one posts a response to my question how do I query them back on the posting.

second asside how the hell do i get html to show up properly on here ive tried '' "" () {} :(

be gentil im a newby and already got punched in the face on here :( second post and someone dropped a load of my score :(

Comment: $content=str_replace("\n", '', $content); keep the double quotes on the first parameter!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two chars which are used for line endings, `\n` (ASCII: 10, Unix/Linux) and `\r` (ASCII: 13, Mac OS). On windows the combination of those two is used `\r\n`. To get rid of all of them use something like this:

```
$str = str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "\r\n"), '', $input);
```

Answer (score 4):

This will replace the **string** "carriage return". I am pretty sure you want to replace the character defining a carriage return, which is `\r`. Also replace the newline char: `\n` as it is also defining a new line. ;)

```
$content = preg_replace("/\n|\r/", '', $content);
```

Answer (score 1):

to replace use

carriage return

```
$content=str_replace("\r", '', $content);
```

new line

```
$content=str_replace("\n", '', $content);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$content = preg_replace("/\n|\r/", '', $content);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
// Add all the carriage returns to the array that you wanted to replace
$carrage_returns = array("\r\n", "\n\r", "\n", "\r", "<br />");
$replace_with = ''; // empty string
$content = str_replace($carrage_returns, $replace_with, $content);
```